# Open in browser intent when link also redirects with deep-linking

Tags: android, android-intent, browser, uri, deep-linking

There are buttons in my app where I would like to let the user open them in the browser. This can be done with starting an `ACTION_VIEW` intent using the URI as data.

This will then simply offer browsers to open the URI. The problem is, these URIs I am using are also connected via deep linking to my application, so if the user already chose to open this links in my app I am getting into an infinite cycle.

Is there a way to force the user to use a browser? On some devices `com.android.browser` is not installed, so trying to start this application directly is not an option. Is there maybe a way to do a `ACTION_VIEW` intent request and remove my app from the possible options in this case?

Comment: `these URIs I am using are also connected via deep linking to my application,`Sorry i do not understand this. Did you mean to tell that your app appears in the browser list the user can choose from?

Comment: @greenapps Yes, exactly. Which is also intended.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `<data android:scheme="http" />` to the intent-filter.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I cannot offer a proper solution. The only workaround, I could come up with, was limiting my intent-filter to `https` and opening the system browser using `http` URLs. Chrome would then follow the `http->https` redirect without opening my app again.